# Numbering Procedure and Algorithm Independently in algorithm2e

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithm2e

I want to use [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) to generate two `procedure` and two `algorithm`. The `procedure` and `algorithm` may be interleaved with one another, and both `procedure` and `algorithm` have their **independent** counter number.

I used the option `procnumbered` to [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) so that the `procedure` environment can be numbered, but I find another problem: the `procedure` and `algorithm` environment only share one counter number. How can I number these two environments separately, each with its own counter?

As an example, how can I number the `procedure` as 1, and the `algorithm` as 1 too (not 2).
Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[procnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
  \caption{myproc()}
  This is a procedure
\end{procedure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  This is a procedure
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both environments use the `algocf` counter; you can teach LaTeX to use another one for procedures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[procnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{procedure}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{procedure}{\let\c@algocf\c@procedure}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}[!htp]
  \caption{myproc()}
  This is a procedure
\end{procedure}

\begin{algorithm}[!htp]
  \caption{My algorithm}
  This is a procedure
\end{algorithm}

\begin{procedure}[!htp]
  \caption{myproc()}\label{aproc}
  This is a procedure
\end{procedure}

\begin{procedure}[!htp]
  \caption{myproc()}
  This is a procedure
\end{procedure}

\begin{algorithm}[!htp]
  \caption{My algorithm}
  This is a procedure
\end{algorithm}

Procedure~\ref{aproc}

\end{document}
```

[image]